# Multer file upload exits with a 500 on server but works on localhost (tested with Postman)

Tags: node.js, express, file, multer

I am implementing a file upload for a Node.js (Express) backend using multer as a middlewear to handle the patched form data. When running the application on localhost uploads work perfectly fine (using Postman formdata); however, when using it comes to using my server multer continues to return a 500 exit code.
Despite various modifications over the past two days I did not manage to upload any files to my servers file system.

Since I am quite new to node.js and multer any help is highly appreciated

---

Frontend form data

```
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileType', 'img');
        formData.append('filePath', 'uploads/img/profile');
        formData.append('profileImg', input.files[0]);

        fetch("https://****", {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        })
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => ("Error occurred", err));
```

---

Backend express server setting (just an excerpt where I think any problem might occur)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://****');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Range');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

app.use(express.static('uploads'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //prev set to false
app.use(cookieParser());

AuthorizationRouter.routesConfig(app);
UsersRouter.routesConfig(app);
```

---

Backend Multer setup

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fileSizeLimit;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `./${req.body.filePath}/`)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, `${uniqueSuffix}_${file.originalname}`)
    }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    //Handling more cases here - just for illustrative purposes 
    let fileRestriction;
    switch (req.body.fileType) {
        case 'file':
            fileRestriction = ['image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', 'image/jpeg'];
            fileSizeLimit = 100000000; // = 100mb
            break;
    }
    fileRestriction.includes(file.mimetype) === true ? cb(null, true) : cb(null, false);
}

exports.upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: fileSizeLimit
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
})
```

---

Backend multer usage as middlewear

```
app.patch('/users/:userId', [
    ValidationMiddleware.validJWTNeeded,
    Upload.upload.fields([
        {name: 'profileImg', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'cv', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'voiceMessage', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'brochure', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'video', maxCount: 1}
    ]),
    UsersController.patchById
]);
```

Comment: Try using `path` to specify the directory `cb(null, path.join(__dirname, \`./${req.body.filePath}\`));`

Comment: thanks for your reply
Unfortunately I am still encountering the 500 error code

Comment: Do you get an error message if you try log the error?

Comment: Not when using localhost. When I run the code on the server I have not implemented any logging yet. Suppose that is what I am going to do next :D

Comment: I logged the following error with Multer: 2021-05-26 17:40:37 [31merror[39m: unknown error Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: I think i found the solution

Comment: Will post the answer here for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify `Content-Type` header when sending FormData with fetch. If you do, it messes with the form boundary the browser applies for you which makes the request not parseable when it gets to the server.

Do the following instead:

```js
fetch("https://****", {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  },
  body: formData
});
```